# Why does new api module needs composer.json?

Tags: magento2, api

I followed alanstorm's magento 2 guides and now I am 
in Magento world for a little more than a month.
https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/#magento-2-mvc

I've come across this tutorial about creating rest-api
https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-custom-rest-api/
it says to make a composer.json and I don't actually know why 
I need this or where to use this.

I didn't make composer.json file to make
non-api modules and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `composer.json` is included in your custom module to define metadata and declare external and third-party dependencies that it needs in order for it to function. As **Magento 2** uses [composer](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/composer-integration.html#overview) to package components.

However, your custom module still works if you are using it directly in your Magento webshop(like you are installing it manually) but if you plan or want to submit it to the Magento Marketplace you should include the `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

While a Magento 2 module/extension can function without it, the main purpose of the composer.json file is to let composer manage that module/extension.

The existence of composer.json allows:

- installing the module through composer
- composer to figure out the module's/extension's dependencies
- the upgrade of the module through composer

Also, form what I've read `\Magento\Framework\Module\PackageInfo` is also related to the existence of the composer.json file, so you might want to take a look at that, too.

Cheers,
Radu

Comment: Thank you Raud!

Comment: It's Radu :) you're welcome! @magefms beat me to it :P